# Centering All Site Content with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I center all my site content with Boostrap (no matter what the width of the browser is)?  Here's a fiddle that demonstrates how the content tends to skew slightly towards the right when I would expect it to be centered: http://jsfiddle.net/Fqzuu/5/embedded/result/

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="whitespaceOnLeft" class="span2"></div>
    <div id="allSiteContent" class="span8">
        <h1 class="text-center">My Site</h1>

        <div>I'd like my site's content to all be centered, a common web design paradigm.  However, 'container' seems to skew toward the right; using 'container-fluid' seems to skew toward the left.  (More obvious when you make your browser narrower.)</div>
    </div>

    <div id="whitespaceOnRight" class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fought with Bootstrap centering for a while and have never found a perfect, responsive solution.

The best solution I've found it to add this to my CSS:

```
.pull-center{text-align:center;margin:0 auto !important;float:none !important;}
```

And then use the "pull-center" class as desired ("container-fluid" works better):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="whitespaceOnLeft" class="span2"></div>
    <div id="allSiteContent" class="span8 pull-center">
        <h1>My Site</h1>

        <div>I'd like my site's content to all be centered, a common web design paradigm.  However, 'container' seems to skew toward the right; using 'container-fluid' seems to skew toward the left.  (More obvious when you make your browser narrower.)</div>
    </div>

    <div id="whitespaceOnRight" class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/bGFSz/

I also discovered that Bootstrap now provides a 'pagination-centered' class, but it doesn't really work for what you're trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class.

.center {margin: 0 auto;}